# Feature that has many zeroes - multivariate gaussian

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution

I am working with multivariate Gaussian distribution (MVG) to detect anomalies in time-series data. I have two features and thousands of observations. The first feature (left) has a very good normal distribution after applying "moving-averages" and Z-score normalization. However, the second feature has many zeroes and doesn't follow the normal distribution. Usually, my anomalies exist where feature-1 with a high score and feature-2 with a low score (especially zero). If it finds an outlier that has high scores in both features, it wouldn't call it.  Because, in theory, MVG uses the covariance between feature1 and 2 and calls the predictions. Now my concerns are.

1. Feature-2 zeroes are important to find outliers and I don't want to remove them. If I don't, it violates the normal distribution assumption. What should I do in this case?
2. Also, in some rare cases where feature-1 and 2 have the highest scores, it detects outliers. Does it mean MVG is not working well or the first concern is somehow affecting how well the model works?

[image]

Comment: You pretty clearly don’t have multivariate Gaussian data. Why is the MVG assumption so crucial?

Comment: Because the model works well with data with a normal/gaussian distribution.

Comment: You violate that assumption or normality. However, there are many misconceptions about when normality is required. What model are you using?

Comment: I am using EllipticEnvelope from sklearn [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.EllipticEnvelope.html)